# How do I bind values into an Array of Strings using *ngFor?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm working with Reactive Forms way.
I want to bind values into an array of strings, for example:

```
The list of fruits will be populated in the input radio.

//<pre>{{ form.value | json }}</pre>
{
    "favorite_fruits": [
        "Banana",
        "Apple",
    ]
}

<form [formGroup]="form" >
    <pre>{{ form.value | json }}</pre>
    <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
        <button type="button" (click)="getFavoriteFruits().push(createFavoriteFruits())" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">add FavoriteFruits</button>
    </div>
    <div formArrayName="favorite_fruits" *ngFor="let h of getFavoriteFruits()!.controls; let indexFavoriteFruits = index;">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label id="">Favorite Fruits</label>
            <div *ngIf="(fruits$ | async) as fruits">
                <div *ngFor="let fruit of fruits; let indexFruit = index;">
                    <input type="radio" [formControlName]="indexFavoriteFruits" [value]="fruit.name">{{ fruit.name }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>



ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getFruits();
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        "favorite_fruits": this.formBuilder.array([
            this.createFavoriteFruits()
        ]),
    });
}
createFavoriteFruits() {
    return this.formBuilder.control('', []);
}
getFavoriteFruits(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('favorite_fruits') as FormArray;
}
getFruits() {
    this.fruits$ = of ([{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Banana"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Apple"
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Pear"
        }])
        .pipe(
            delay(2000)
        )
}
```

I was trying to using `[formControlName]="indexFavoriteFruits"` (inside brackets) and the error below was given:

```
error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
<input type="radio" [formControlName]="indexFavoriteFruits" [value]="fruit.name">{{ fruit.name }}
```

I also tried to using `formControlName="indexFavoriteFruits"`, but I got another error:

```
core.js:6456 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'favorite_fruits -> indexFavoriteFruits'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using `formControlName="favorite_fruits"`

indexFavoriteFruits is the index you are getting in the *ngFor, thats why it is interpreted as number. The correct formcontrolname is favorite_fruits

Comment: Still doesn't work. The error it was given: core.js:6456 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'favorite_fruits -> favorite_fruits'

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're using Angular version < v9, which accept only a `string` as a value for `formControlName`. Which is changed since Angular v9 to accept `string|number|null`.

So, you need to cast the `indexFavoriteFruits` to a string or any because the `formControlName` accepts strings only.

You can cast it to `any` using `$any` method, like the following:

```html
<input type="radio" [formControlName]="$any(indexFavoriteFruits)" [value]="fruit.name">
```